# Magnetic Vector potential and it's boundary conditions

Tags: magnetic-fields, potential, boundary-conditions

The boundary condition for magnetic field **B** is:

$\mathbf B_{above} - \mathbf B_{below}$ = $\mu_0(\mathbf K $ **x** $\hat n$)

But from this, how do we get the boundary conditions for vector potential **A** which is:

$\partial \mathbf A_{above}/ \partial n-\partial \mathbf A_{below}/ \partial n$ $= -\mu_0 \mathbf K$.

Can someone please elaborate.

Comment: Use $B=\nabla \times A$